# Postgres: Delete a jsonb key, in a recursive merging function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to add support for deleting a key in jsonb, when setting a value to "__delete__".

I found a good function for merging keys here:
http://blog.bguiz.com/2017/json-merge-postgresql/
However it doesn't support deleting keys from the objects.
Here is it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."jsonb_merge_recurse"("orig" jsonb, "delta" jsonb)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."jsonb" AS $BODY$
    select
        jsonb_object_agg(
            coalesce(keyOrig, keyDelta),
            case
                when valOrig isnull then valDelta
                when valDelta isnull then valOrig
                when (jsonb_typeof(valOrig) <> 'object' or jsonb_typeof(valDelta) <> 'object') then valDelta
                else jsonb_merge_recurse(valOrig, valDelta)
            end
        )
    from jsonb_each(orig) e1(keyOrig, valOrig)
    full join jsonb_each(delta) e2(keyDelta, valDelta) on keyOrig = keyDelta
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

I'd like to delete the key from the object, in case valDelta = '__delete__'.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `"__deleted__"` gets you into trouble with some of the parsing mechanisms in PostgreSQL. I would recommend using `NULL` to represents a deleted value. With that said, you could simplify the function to be as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."jsonb_merge"("orig" jsonb, "delta" jsonb)
    RETURNS "pg_catalog"."jsonb" AS
    $$
      SELECT jsonb_strip_nulls($1 || $2);
    $$
    LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

The [`||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) operator concatenates two JSONB objects together and gives preferences to any key-value pair that is on the right hand side. The [`jsonb_strip_nulls`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function will remove any keys that have a `null` value associated with them (And note: `null` in [JSONB is treated differently than a SQL `NULL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE), so doing a `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` test on a JSONB `null` will not work).

This does not handle nested JSON objects, but will suffice if you only have top-level key-value pairs.

Comment: Is there any chance that there is something similar when value of the key in jsonb is "" (empty) and no null?